# Node.js http socket closed after 90 seconds without timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to keep a connection opened between an http.Server and a net.Socket client.
But the connection is automatically closed after 90 seconds without emitting 'timeout' event. I didn't find any explanation about this behaviour. So if anyone knows what's going on, please let me know.

Note that this connection uses WebSocket protocol. Thus ping/pong data are sent through it.

See below a basic code reproducing this behaviour:

```
const http = require('http')
const net = require('net')
const PORT = 8080

const server = http.createServer()
server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const timestamp = Date.now()
    console.log('connection')
    socket.on('timeout', () => {
        console.log('sSocket timeout') // Never called
    })
    socket.on('close', () => {
        console.log('close', (Date.now() - timestamp) / 1000) // 90 seconds (60s sometimes)
        createConnection()
    })
})
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('HTTP/1.1 server is listening on port:', PORT)
})

/** Creates new connection. */
function createConnection() {
    const socket = net.createConnection({ port: PORT })
    socket.on('timeout', () => {
        console.log('cSocket timeout') // Never called
    })
}
createConnection()
```

Comment: Your creating a HTTP server, but from what I can remember a Wesocket over HTTP needs to go via the `upgrade` event.  From node docs -> `If this event is not being listened for and the response status code is 101 Switching Protocols, clients receiving an upgrade header will have their connections closed.`  I believe 90 seconds is the default HTTP timeout, so your basically not even getting as far as creating a WebSocket connection.

Comment: You're right. The server sends 'HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout' to the client in the basic code above. And the connection stays open using the 'upgrade' event. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

As @Keith explained in the comments, the http.Server is closing the connection due to the HTTP timeout. To keep a connection open, the client must use the "Connection: Upgrade" header (as WebSocket does). On the server side, you need to listen for the 'upgrade' event emitted from the http.Server and use the socket returned in the parameters.

See the doc about 'upgrade' event: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-upgrade

Solution code:

```
const http = require('http')
const net = require('net')
const PORT = 8080

const server = http.createServer()
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
    socket.write('Hello')
})
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('HTTP/1.1 server is listening on port:', PORT)
})

const socket = net.createConnection({ port: PORT })
socket.write(
    `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n` +
    'Upgrade: {Your Protocol}\r\n' +
    'Connection: Upgrade\r\n' +
    '\r\n'
)
socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
```